# Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

no need for answer unless you feel you want to contribute :)

So I feel stupid as hell I been banging my head against a wall with this for an hour... 
but for the sake of your head ill explain the problem,
I had a mark-up that looks like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="MainSearchNewDesign" %>
```

And code behind that looks like this :

```
public partial class MainSearchNewDesign : System.Web.UI.Page
```

And still I got that damn error, the reason for that is that I forgot that if I have the a different file ( with a different name ) with the same class name the compiler still takes into account and tells you to go bang your head onto the wall...

Man I feel really stupid now... but I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never place multiple files ( even if they have different names ) that contains the same class name in the same library.

Answer (score 0):

That happens in Visual Studio if you copy and paste a .aspx page. You rename the page but not the class in the code behind.

One of those mistakes you only ever make once.